# Strange issue in saving class in NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I have the next class:

```
class UnreadMessages: NSObject {

    let publicID: String
    let messagesCount: Int

    init(publicID: String, messagesCount: Int) {
        self.publicID = publicID
        self.messagesCount = messagesCount
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.publicID = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("publicID") as! String
        self.messagesCount = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("messagesCount") as! Int
    }

    func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encodeObject(publicID, forKey: "publicID")
        aCoder.encodeObject(messagesCount, forKey: "messagesCount")
    }
}
```

and I'm saving it in NSUserDefault as:

```
var chatList = [UnreadMessages]()
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(chatList), forKey: "ChatList")
```

and then I try to get these values as:

```
if let data = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("ChatList") as? NSData {
    let blog = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithData(data)
    print(blog)
}
```

but when I try to print my `blog.publicID` it gives me the next error:

> error: :2:10: error: 'UnreadMessages' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context blog as! UnreadMessages

How can I fix that?

Comment: Your `UnreadMessages` class needs to conform to the `NSCoding` protocol.

Comment: @rmaddy I've updated my question. Is that okay?

Comment: You should add `, NSCoding` after `NSObject` on the `class` line.

Comment: And perhaps the `unarchiveObjectWithData` line should have a `as [UnreadMessages]` added to the end.

Comment: @rmaddy now I get `expression produced error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.` when I'm trying to print my `blog.first.publicID`

Comment: That's probably from force unwrapping a nil optional.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm checking, it writes to my NSUserDefaults, but when I call `if let data = ` it returns me `nil`. What is wrong there?